# org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled. Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]

Tags: java, kerberos, presto-jdbc

I am trying to execute the hive table query in presto  using Kerberos authentication, But it failed

Caused by: com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Error opening Hive split hdfs://ip-10-13-9-237.xxxx.com:8020/user/hive/warehouse/extended_test_db_hive2.db/table_with_all_data_types/000000_0_copy_2 (offset=0, length=124) using org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]

Anyone please help

Comment: Can you provide how you are connecting ?

Comment: I am using this URL format presto://host-name:port/database ,connectivity is success,but seems ,its failed with some hive related table execution failed with mentioned error.

Comment: I'd look into the documentation for presto and how to use it with kerberos.  Like I said in my answer below, you aren't passing the required authentication information (Cause of the error) you need to understand how presto passes that information and follow it.

Answer (score 0):

This error message tells me that you aren't actually using the correct authentication mechanism.  You presented [nothing] or [user/name password] and it's expecting [Kerberos] or [token].  You likely need to use a different connection string to make sure you connect via kerberos.

Usually you have to change your connection to something like:

```
jdbc:hive2://[my_hive_server]:[port]/[database];principal=myPrincipel@EXAMPLE.COM
```

or adjust your jaas config to something like:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useTicketCache=false
doNotPrompt=true
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="<QuerySurge Install Dir>/QuerySurge/agent/mykeytab.keytab"
principal="myPrincipel@EXAMPLE.COM"
};
```

Comment: Actually am using presto facebook driver , it's not accept the URL like below ,returns connection is null jdbc:hive2://[my_hive_server]:[port]/[database];principal=myPrincipel@EXAMPLE.COM

Comment: Every URL will have it's own way to add kerberos information.  These where to examples, not necessarily to be followed exactly.

Comment: SSL is mandatory for Kerberos authentication?